# Stanford Chinese Word Segmenter in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, stanford-nlp

I am just starting with the Chinese Word Segmenter, and I would like to use it in my Android application (primarily to parse the Tatoeba example sentences). I'm not really sure where to start on this, and am looking for documentation and/or examples of using it on Android. Additionally, I imported the .jar as a library in Android Studio, but I am having trouble adding the Source and Javadoc to the library, the primary problem being that the library doesn't show up in the External Libraries folder in the Project View. Some good starting questions I have are:

- Which classes do I need to use to segment text?
- How does the segmenter handle English names?
- Is there a page for the documentation besides [this](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter-faq.html)? (I need documentation for using it in Java, not just as a command line tool)
- Are there any examples of using the segmenter in Android?
- Do I also need to have the CoreNLP library?
- Are there simpler alternatives to the Stanford segmenter?

Sorry for such a basic question but I am really not understanding how to use it at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a jar in your CLASSPATH with the code and you need a jar with these files in it (they can all be found in the Chinese models jar):

```
edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict-chris6.ser.gz
edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/ctb.gz
StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties
```

You could include this jar from the main distribution to get the code:

```
stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar
```

The file I referenced above is available with the Chinese models jar found here:  https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

You are going to have to create some small jars if you want to integrate this with an Android app since there are very strict size requirements.  I would advise cutting out most of the code that is not necessary for just running the segmenter.

If you use the stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar , this is some sample code:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.util.*;

public class PipelineExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties("-props", "StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties");
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit");
    // set up Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // build annotation for a review
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("...Chinese text to segment...");
    // annotate the review
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        System.out.println(token);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will want to do some work to shrink the jars down to the bare minimum, ultimately this will require removing lots of classes and making sure things still run properly.

You could also download the standalone segmenter, which runs the same process, more info here:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.html

It might be easier to use the standalone segmenter distribution.  It will have a demo called SegDemo.java which shows Java API usage in that case.  The sample code I provided above will not work if you use the classes from the standalone segmenter.